# append text after match from multiple file locations

Tags: sed

Am a noob when it comes to coding so bear with me... I am trying to write a script that will input data from 3 separate files into 3 specific locations within a text file - for example:
edited to read easier

```
#start of script
start_of_line1_text "$1" end_of_line1_text
start_of_line2_text "$2" end_of_line2_text
start_of_line3_text "$3" end_of_line3_text
#output to text when done   

$1 is the value in text1
$2 is the value in text2
$3 is the value in text3
```

I am thinking of using sed but cant quite work out how this would be done...

Or just insert a word at $1 after matching random_text? ie:

```
sed '/start_of_line1_text/ a middle_of_line1_text' input
```

Also on a larger scale - if text1,2 and 3 had multiple values in how could you import these values 1 at a time and save a new file each time? so for example:

```
text1 = 
a
b
c

text2 = 
e
f
g

text3 = 
h
i
j


#start of script
start_of_line1_text "line one of text1" end_of_line1_text
start_of_line2_text "line one of text2" end_of_line2_text
start_of_line3_text "line one of text3" end_of_line3_text
#output to text when done
```

then:

```
#start of script
start_of_line1_text "line two of text1" end_of_line1_text
start_of_line2_text "line two of text2" end_of_line2_text
start_of_line3_text "line two of text3" end_of_line3_text
#output to text when done
```

Im not fussy on the language used I am just a bit stuck as to how to fit this all together....

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I tried hard to understand what you're trying to do, but I don't get it. It seems you mix pseudocode and the input/output; additionally, the text is oversimplified. Is it really identical on each line? Probably not. You can improve this question by making more clear what you want to happen, separating (pseudo)code and input/output, and showing what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

This problem suits very well `awk`.

Give this a try:

```
awk '!f[FNR] {f[FNR]=("out" FNR ".txt"); print "#start of script" >f[FNR]} {print "random_text \"" $0 "\" some_other_text" >f[FNR]} END {for(n in f) print "#output to text when done">f[n]}' text1 text2 text3
```

The output files are generated in current directory `out1.txt` and `out2.txt` etc.

You can provide any number of text files as input at the end of the command.

There is below the script file version with additional parameters:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
!f[FNR] {
  f[FNR]=("out" FNR ".txt")
  print first >f[FNR]
}
{ 
  print start $0 end >f[FNR]
}
END {
  for(n in f) print last>f[n]
}
```

The test:

```
chmod +x ./script.awk
./script.awk -v first="#start of script"                          \
             -v start="random_text \"" -v end="\" some_other_text"\
             -v last="#output to text when done"                  \
             text1 text2 text3
```

Answer (score 0):

what I have so far is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub rtrim { my $s = shift; $s =~ s/\s+$//;       return $s };

sub read_file_line {
my $fh = shift;

if ($fh and my $line = <$fh>) {
chomp $line;
return [split(/\t/,$line)];
}
return;
}

open(my $f1, "file1.txt");
open(my $f2, "file2.txt");
open(my $f3, "file3.txt");
open(FILE, ">group.txt") or die "Cannot open file";

my $pair1 = read_file_line($f1);
my $pair2 = read_file_line($f2);
my $pair3 = read_file_line($f3);

while ($pair1 and $pair2 and $pair3) {

printf '%s,',$pair1->[0] ;
printf "%s\n",$pair2->[0] ;
printf '%s,',$pair3->[0] ;

printf FILE " line1_text\n" ;
printf FILE " line2_text\n" ;
printf FILE " line3_text\n" ;
printf FILE " start_of_line4_text\"%s\end_of_line4_text\n",$pair3->[0] ;
printf FILE " start_of_line5_text\"%s\end_of_line5_text\n",$pair2->[0] ;
printf FILE " start_of_line6_text\"%s\end_of_line6_text\n",rtrim($pair1->[0]) ;
printf FILE " line7_text\n" ;
printf FILE " line8_text\n\n\n" ;



$pair1 = read_file_line($f1);
$pair2 = read_file_line($f2);
$pair3 = read_file_line($f3);

}

close($f1);
close($f2);
close($f3);
close(FILE) ;
```